Using alive-progress together with pywikibot gives OSError: Target stream <stderr> is neither stdin (<stdout>) nor stderr (<stderr>)
I'm trying to use an alive-bar progress bar (see https://pypi.org/project/alive-progress/), keeping an eye on some PyWikiBot operations. Sadly, i've got the following error when PyWikiBot seems to access stderr:
Target stream  is neither stdin () nor stderr ()
My code looks as follows:
for pg in PreloadingGenerator(pages, groupsize=50):
    with alive_bar(50) as bar:
        fp = FilePage(pg)
        fi = fp.oldest_file_info
        # ... do some more things with FilePage and FileInfo which takes time...
        bar()

Stacktrace:
Exception has occurred: OSError
Target stream <stderr> is neither stdin (<stdout>) nor stderr (<stderr>)
  File ".../analyze_text.py", line 48, in fill_db
    fi = fp.oldest_file_info
  File ".../analyze_text.py", line 202, in <module>
    fill_db(con, pages)
  File "/usr/local/bin/pwb", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
OSError: Target stream <stderr> is neither stdin (<stdout>) nor stderr (<stderr>)

What am i doing wrong?
